# Generic way to extract text from a Java Application

Tags: java, desktop-application

I need to extract all text from all windows open on desktop. With windows application it is relatively easy to get this working i.e. using `SendMessage` + `WM_GETTEXT`.

But this technique does not work with Java applications. Is there a way to extract text from Java applications or is it a wild goose chase?

Comment: @user544550 Good day. Did you find out how to do this?

Comment: Perhaps you could add a listener to each text field you create in the app.  When you trigger it, it'll gather all the data of its field.